# Add class to element if y-position bigger as another element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a class to an element as soon as the users' scroll-position has "hit" a special - other - element.

I try to use that code therefore

```
var hands = $(".sw_3--breit");
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
// The next line is the one I am asking for help
       if (scroll >= window.innerHeight) 
       {
          hands.addClass("fixed");
        } else {
          hands.removeClass("fixed");
        }
});
```

Which works nice by adding the class after the scroll is bigger then the users display-height I guess. But I want to add - and afterwards also remove - a class when then user has "hit" another element.

What I am asking for is something - very roughly and stupid I know - like:

```
var other_elements_position = $(".other_element"().position;
if (scroll >= other_elements_position)
```

How can I achieve that? And I already do use jquery for other things, so using jquery there would make sense I guess.

Thanks!

Comment: `$("..sw_3--breit").position;` i doubt on selector and the method applied on it? What do you expect from `.position`?

Comment: It'S wrong of course. I just wanted to demo roughyl what I wanto to have as an output: $(".other_element").y_position_of_that_object;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people that got the same problem as I do have, this worked for me:

```
var hands = $(".sw_3--breit");
var hands_original = $(".sw_8").position();
var hands_off = $("#target_agentur").position();
var hands_corrected = (hands_original.top + 680) // here I add a small delay to the trigger of the "animation"
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >= hands_corrected && scroll <= hands_off.top) // I doublecheck against 2 heights
{
        hands.addClass("fixed");
    } else {
        hands.removeClass("fixed");
    }
});
```